Unable to open the workflow in designer using vs code
I have created a stateless workflow in the workspace and trying to open with designer by right-click on the workflow.json > select "open in designer" option.
But it is showing the below error:

What is this error stating about and how to resolve this issue?
Update 1:
Tried removing the dependencies folder in the .azurelogicapps directory in the local user profile as instructed in this GitHub issue #3925. Still, the same issue occurring.
I have the latest Azure Functions Core Tools (x64 bit) version installed in my system.

Currently, your root folder is vivkesalaws, and testala101 is a subfolder; that's why VS Code is complaining about the project root.
testala101 must be the root folder in your project. You might encounter other problems after that  but at least this error will be resolved.
Example:


Yes, this is the issue, you given the limelight - thanks @10p
